# POWERSHELL execute a file powershell script but from different path

Tags: powershell, execute

I want to execute a powershell script file, it works but if I am in the same path that the script

```
....
$toto=(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\toto\Desktop\titi\tutu)
```

I work with the variable $toto

I execute the script from :

```
 PS C:\Users\toto\Desktop\titi> C:\Users\toto\Desktop\titi\script.ps1 = it works
```

but when I am below s subdir, not knowing the current "working directory"  :

```
 C:\Users\toto\Desktop\ C:\Users\toto\Desktop\titi\script.ps1
```

how to resolve that please

Comment: It looks like the script assumes to be running from the same directory in which it is located. Either make sure that you make that the current location before invoking, or, preferably, update the script to refer to its own location explicitly, using the automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable.

Comment: how to use it please

Comment: Your actual problem (*"it does not work...*) could likely be easily isolated to not knowing the current "working directory" if we saw the _line where your script fails_ along with the _subsequent error message provided_.

Comment: yes indeed, so I use $PSScriptRoot\tutu, but not resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something like this:

```bsh
$toto=(Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot\tutu")
```